Existence of weakly continuous regular conditional probability
Let $X$,$A$ be  compact metric spaces. We consider Borel probability measures. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X\times A$. Let $\hat{\mu}$ be the marginal of $\mu$ on $X$, i.e., for every Borel subset $X_0\subset X$, one has $\hat{\mu}(X_0)=\mu(X_0\times A)$.
By Proposition D.8 (1) of  Discrete-time Markov control processes (by Onésimo Hernández-Lerma and Jean Bernard Lasserre), there is Markov kernel (product regular conditional probability=RCP) $\phi$ from $X$ to $A$ such that $$\mu(X_0\times A_0)=\int_{X_0}\phi(A_0|x)\hat{\mu}(dx)$$ for all Borel subsets $X_0\subset X$, $A_0\subset A$.
Let $P(A)$ be the set of probability measures on $A$. A map $\phi:X\to P(A)$ is called weakly continuous (aka weak Feller property) if for every continuous function $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$, the function $X\to \mathbb{R},\quad x\mapsto\int_Af(a)d\phi_x(a)$ is continuous.
Question: Is there a condition on $\mu$ ensuring the existence of a weakly continuous RCP $\phi:X\to P(A)$?
